# Angular 2 Alternative to Angular2-busy?

Tags: angular

I built my app to work with angular2-busy:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

It works great for showing a loading animation for observables.

Unfortunately, it's not setup to work with '--aot' when I bundle the project: `ng build --prod --aot` as it errors.

For UX purposes, I'd really prefer to have a loading animation when a user performs a search and I haven't been able to find a good tutorial/process on doing this manually.

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean that you want to display loaders every time you make an `http` request?

Comment: This is a MEAN app, and I'm using router.get to return json results from a MongoDB.

Comment: Have you found a solution? @Vassilis Pits do you know I show loading on all' http call? I have open a thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150759/how-show-loading-as-long-there-are-pending-request-angular2

Comment: It also has an issue with newer versions of a@angular/common, @angular/core- check this link https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually if you subscribe to Observables, for example using jsrx you can setup something like this:

Angular2 Component:

```
    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'sd-offer',
      templateUrl: 'offer.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['offer.component.css']
    })
    export class OfferComponent {
      public offers$: Observable<Offer>;
      private busy:boolean;

      constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>, public routerext: RouterExtensions) {
        this.busy = true;
        // returns observable
        this.offers$ = store.let(getOffers);    

        this.offers$.subscribe(
          (x) => { // next
            console.log('Next ' + x);
            this.busy = false;
          },
          (err) => { // error
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
            this.busy = false;        
          },
          () => { // completed
            console.log('Completed');
            this.busy = false;
          }      
        );        
      }
  // ...
}
```

Component's HTML template:

```
<span *ngIf="busy">
  <h3>Loading...</h3>
</span>

<div *ngIf="!busy">
  <a *ngFor="let offer of (offers$ | async)" href="{{offer.link}}">
      <img src="{{offer.img}}" alt="{{offer.name}}">
  </a>
</div>
```

This will display

#### Loading...

while data is being fetched in the background.

Alternatively You can replace the loading... string with a spinner img

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [pull request](https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy/pull/67) adding AOT support.